# invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ c++?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am trying to use pthread_create() but it always gives me this error invalid conversion from `void*` to `void* ( * )(void*)`

This error is in the 3rd argument. Could someone help me with this error ?

```
void Print_data(void *ptr) {
    cout<<"Time of Week = " <<std::dec<<iTOW<<" seconds"<<endl;
    cout<<"Longitude = "<<lon<<" degree"<<endl;
    cout<<"Latitude  = "<<lat<<" degree"<<endl;
    cout<<"Height Above Sea = "<<alt_MSL<<" meters"<<endl;    
  }

int call_thread() 
  {
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (void *) &Print_data, NULL);
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: why are you casting to `(void*)` in the first place?

Comment: Sounds like you don't need the cast to void* as it expects a pointer to function returning void anyway?

Comment: The title says `void* (*)(void*)` but the description says `void* ()(void)` - which one is the correct error message? Please clarify because I just rejected an edit which guessed.

Comment: @Philipp, they both said the same thing, but one got interpreted as markdown. The correct form is obviously the one not mangled by markdown, and matching the actual parameter type of `pthread_create`

Comment: *cough* `PrintData` should be `extern "C"` *cough*

Answer (score 18):

The error is that you're converting the function pointer (`void* (*)(void*)`) to an object pointer (`void*`), when `pthread_create` expects a function pointer for that argument. There's no implicit conversion to undo the dodgy conversion you've done, hence the error.

The answer is to not do that:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &Print_data, NULL);
```

and you'll also need to modify `Print_data` to return `void*` to match the Posix threads interface:

```
void *Print_data(void *ptr) {
    // print stuff
    return NULL;  // or some other return value if appropriate
}
```

As noted in the comments, there are various other issues with using this C library directly from C++; in particular, for portability, the thread entry function should be `extern "C"`. Personally, I'd recommend using the standard C++ thread library (or Boost's implementation, if you're stuck with a pre-2011 version of the language).

Comment: That also won't compile (or at least not cleanly), since `pthread_create` expects a function that returns a `void *` value, and the function `Print_data` is declared as `void Print_data` - it's relatively easy to fix by adding a `*` after `void` and `return NULL;` at the end of the function.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Hence the last line of my answer. I've added a bit more clarification in case others don't spot that.

Comment: I done exactly what you said , Now it gave me another error that says undefined reference to pthread ??

Comment: @Zeyad: Assuming you're compiling with GCC, you'll need `-lpthread` to link with the pthreads library.

Comment: @Zeyed: Are you linking with the pthread library `-lpthread`?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: You added that AFTER my comment... But probably STARTED before... ;) I do that too at times - quickly get an answer, then realize that I have missed some small point, and go back to edit it.

Comment: And to avoid the crash, remember to join() your thread or you probably won't see anything.

Comment: no I am not linking with this library I didn't know so :) thanks

Comment: According to the standard, `Print_data` must also be `extern "C"`.  Otherwise, the code shouldn't compile, even though some widely used C++ compilers prefer to ignore the standard, and  not issue a diagnostic.

Comment: @moose I understand how to join it is a hell of a code but I just wrote this example to find where my problem is... Thanks people you saved me alot of time :)

Comment: @Zeyad. It not that much code:
pthread_join(thread, 0);
If you work with pthreads, you might choose to do such things.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to convert a function pointer into a `void*` here: `(void *) &Print_data`

According to `pthread_create` you need to pass in a function that takes a `void*` and returns a `void*`

So your function signature should be

```
void* Print_data(void *ptr)
```

And your call should be

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &Print_data, NULL);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`pthread_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html) takes the third argument as

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread,
                   const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine)(void*),
                   void *arg);
```

This, `void *(*start_routine)(void*)` is a pointer to a function that takes a `void*` pointer and returns a `void*` pointer.

When you do `&Print_data` and convert the pointer to `void *` , it means you are passing a pointer of type `void*` and not a pointer of type `void *(*start_routine)(void*)` [function pointer].

To be correct, you need to make your return type as `void*` and make the call as `pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &Print_data, NULL);`

Answer (score 2):

You must return `void*`

```
void* Print_data(void *ptr) {
```

to satisfy the needs.

The signature of the function to be passed is

```
void* function(void*);
```

then call `pthread_create` using

```
 pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &Print_data, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

add header file #include
and compile  g++  -lpthread

Comment: add header file #include<cstdlib>
and compile  g++ <file name(*.cpp)> -lpthread

Comment: This should be a comment only. Not a full answer